# HttpClient with HTTPS certificate

Tags: java, csr

I was a bit envious of our Ruby on Rails team who needs to consume the same web services requiring HTTPS request be signed with a certificate. They grab a gem, sign the request with a single line of code, dishes are done...

Java, however, requires that we import the cert to our keystore (trying to avoid this), or create one in memory...that's fine. But, once I do that, it seems like the only option to actually signing requests is using the HttpUrlConnection class. [HttpUrlConnection example](http://blog.chariotsolutions.com/2013/01/https-with-client-certificates-on.html)

I'd like to be able to sign requests using my existing code, which uses apache's DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(); - but I don't see a way to have the Http client sign requests using an in memory keystore.

Anyone faced this?

Comment: By 'web services requiring HTTPS request be signed with a certificate' did you mean trusting the server certificate issuer?

Comment: @gerrytan No, this is a mechanism of the server to trust requests, not the other way around. The server refuses the request if it's not properly signed.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [AuthSSLProtocolSocketFactory.java](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/httpcomponents/oac.hc3x/trunk/src/contrib/org/apache/commons/httpclient/contrib/ssl/AuthSSLProtocolSocketFactory.java?view=markup). You should be able to perform SSL client authentication like this (untested code);

```
Protocol.registerProtocol("https", 
new Protocol("https", new AuthSSLProtocolSocketFactory(keystoreUrl, keystorePassword, truststoreUrl, truststorePassword), 443));
HttpClient httpclient = new HttpClient();
GetMethod httpget = new GetMethod("https://www.whatever.com/");
try {
  httpclient.executeMethod(httpget);
  System.out.println(httpget.getStatusLine());
} finally {
  httpget.releaseConnection();
}
```

Your client certificate goes into keystore pointed by `keystoreUrl`. Read more about this on [HttpClient SSL Guide](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-legacy/sslguide.html).

Comment: Hmmm, this uses org.apache.commons.httpclient* - I thought that this apache namespace was more "up to date" -> org.apache.http.*?